# Can a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be a base for $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

For example, could the vectors $(0, 1, 2)$ and $(1, 0, 2)$ potentially span $\mathbb{R}^2$ and be linearly independent?

I've seen a bunch of articles that say two vectors cannot span $\mathbb{R}^3$ which makes sense to me, but it seems to me that if the last coordinates of the vectors were $0$ then they could span a plane.

I know that normally a candidate basis is disqualified if it has more vectors than needed, but in this case the vector would have more entries than needed so I am not sure if that still holds.

I am asking for my homework as I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Excellent question! presented in an appropriate way. We need more students like you on this site. You are always welcome here $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 8):

The vectors cannot span $\mathbb R^{2}$ because they are not vectors in $\mathbb R^{2}$!. However they span a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, any two linearly independent vectors will span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and any such plane is isomorphic$^\dagger$ as a vector space to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  But do note that $\{(x, y, 0) \ | \ x, y \in \mathbb{R} \} \neq \{(x, y) \ | \ x, y \in \mathbb{R} \} = \mathbb{R}^2$.  This is to say, vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ must have $n$ components *by definition*.

In this same vein, one should not be tempted to think of $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ([a common error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Equality_vs._isomorphism)) even though the horizontal axis of the Cartesian plane is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}$.  Or, as a topologist would say, $\mathbb{R}$ is *[embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology)* in $\mathbb{R}^2$, just as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is inside $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

$^\dagger$Explicitly, if the plane has basis vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, then the isomorphism is determined by $\mathbf{v} \mapsto \langle 1, 0 \rangle$ and $\mathbf{w} \mapsto \langle 0, 1 \rangle$.

Comment: OK I think I got it thanks guys and whoever edited my question!